# Event tree - can I add and mulitply the probabilities like this

Tags: probability, decision-trees

If I have an event tree such as the following:

[image: Event tree]

Is the following solution then correct to get to B or to D:

$(0.1 \times 0.4) + (0.1 \times 0.6 \times 0.7) = 0.082$

Or should I only use the first branch of $0.1$ only once as it follows the same line?

Comment: "*To get to $B$ **and** to $D$*"?  Do you not mean to get to $B$ **or** to $D$?  You can't end at $B$ at the same time as $D$ simultaneously.  As for the probability of ending at $B$ *or* $D$, yes, your calculation is correct.  Alternatively worded you could use $0.1\cdot(0.4+0.6\cdot0.7)$ to get the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I did mean OR by the way, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can answer that question for yourself: recast the problem as though you're starting at the orange dot in the middle and trying to get to either B, C or D. Notice that these are the only possibilities, so the sum of their probabilities *should* be 1.

If I repeat the calculation you gave, I'd get something like:
$$0.4 + 0.6 \cdot 0.3 + 0.6 \cdot 0.7$$
What would happen if I instead used the $0.6$ only once?

Comment: The probabilities wouldn't add up to 1, you're right :) That's a nice explanation